# Regular expression keyword match in URL

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of URL in a large file (20 mb), and I have a set of keywords. If the set of keywords matches the url then I want to extract the URL.

Example:keyword="contact"
URL:http://www.365media.com/offices-and-contact.html

I need a regular expression to match the keywords with my list of URLs.

My Java code:

```
public class FileRead {

    public static void main(String[] ags) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(new File("D:\\Log\\Links.txt"));
        String input;
        String[] reg=new String[]{".*About.*",".*Available.*",".*Author.*",".*Blog.*",".*Business.*",
    ".*Career.*",".*category.*",".*City.*",".*Company.*",".*Contain.*",".*Contact.*",".*Download.*",
    ".*Email.*"};
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            input=in.nextLine();
            //for(String s:reg)
                patternFind(input,".*email.*");
        }

    }
    public static void patternFind(String input,String reg)
    {
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile(reg);
            Matcher m=p.matcher(input);
            while(m.find())
                System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

Comment: What information do you need? Only match/no match or which keyword matched?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match for the existence of any Keyword in the current line, you can simply use

```
for (String s: reg) {
  if (input.contains(s)) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

instead of
    patternFind(input,".*email.*");

Anyways, a regular expression equivalent to match any of the words would be:

```
.*(About|Available|Author|And|So|On...).*
```

I'm not sure which one is faster. String.contains() is simpler, a Pattern is precompiled which *could* perform better when applied many times, as it is the case here.

Answer (score 1):

Why you can't do this:

```
For all line (URLs) in the file check if some of your pattern works on the URL
```

the code is pretty obvious

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give a bit general solution. I think you should be able to adapt the idea to your code.

Supposed you have a list of bare keywords in a file and you read it into a `String[]`, or you hard-code the list of keywords in a `String[]`, for example:

```
String keywords[] = {"about", "available", "email"};
```

For all the keywords, use [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) to make sure they are recognized as literal string. Then concatenate the keywords with bar character `|` as separator (OR), and surround everything with parentheses `()`. The end result will be like this. Alternatively, you can look at the keywords yourself and write the regex without the quoting `\Q` and `\E`. You can also just ignore the `Pattern.quote()` step, if you are sure that the keywords do not contain regex.

```
(\Qabout\E|\Qavailable\E|\Qemail\E)
```

Add `.*` to 2 ends to make it matches the rest of the URL, plus `(?i)` at the beginning to enable case-insensitive match.

```
(?i).*(\Qabout\E|\Qavailable\E|\Qemail\E).*
```

Then you can compile the `Pattern` and call `matcher(inputString).matches()` on each line of input to check whether the URL has the keyword.

If the keyword is too common in a URL, such as "com", "net", "www", and you want to make the search more fine grain, more tweaking must be done.